# Use ございます out of fixed expression

Tags: word-usage

How common is using ございます in spoken Japanese, even in formal polite uses, outside fixed expressions like おはようございます or ありがとうございます

Comment: A decent amount: https://eigobu.jp/magazine/gozaimasu

Answer (score 3):

ございます is very commonly heard in announcements and from people in service roles.

Whether you use it or not depends entirely on your level of ability with the language and the environment you speak Japanese in.